# Inherit autocomplete/suggestion proptypes in wrapper component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I am creating my own custom "wrapper" around a chakraui component, so I can add my own props, methods and whatever I might need later on.

However, one downside of doing this is that I don't get suggestions for the imported chakraui-Button proptypes in Visual Studio Code, but only the new proptype "testPropColor". The other properties are still working, but is there any way of passing them further down so I can see them as suggestions as well?

What I have is this:
**custom-component/button.js**

```js
import { Button as ChakraButton } from '@chakra-ui/react'

export default function Button(properties) {
  const { testPropColor, children, ...props } = properties

  return (
    <ChakraButton color="testPropColor" {...props}>
      {children}
    </ChakraButton>
  )
}
```

And how I am using this in a view:

```js
import Button from 'custom-component/Button'

export default function ViewComponent() {
  return (
    <Button
      bg="red"
      testPropColor="blue">Test</Button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't come with `type` support. So no `type`-intellisense in VSCode.

I highly **highly** ***highly*** suggest adding `TypeScript` to your JS React project.

e.g:

```
interface ButtonProps extends ChakraButton { 
    // you need to get the `ChakraButton` properties type, from '@chakra-ui/react'. 
    // You should be able to import it.
    testPropColor: string;
    bg: string;

}
export function Button(properties: ButtonProps) {

}
```

Just a quick article I found for example [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-strong-reasons-to-use-typescript-with-react-bc987da5d907#:%7E:text=Know%20the%20benefits%20you%20can%20gain%20by%20using%20TypeScript%20with%20React&text=TypeScript%20is%20a%20superset%20of,typing%2C%20classes%2C%20and%20interfaces.&text=This%20means%20you%20can%20start,one%20component%20at%20a%20time.).

If for some reason you don't add TS(?!. you really should) -> then there's prop-types, but I don't suggest using it, compared to TS.

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added Typescript to my project and followed your advice. It works as expected.

Comment: Good luck (: It's a big and beneficial change. I suggest you keep in mind that *any* issue you might have with TS is solveable! (And reading the docs is always useful)